# Getting Patient Analysis Results In HL7 V2.3-V2.3.1-V2.4

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

Getting Patient Analysis Results In HL7 V2.3-V2.3.1-V2.4.
Including analysis date|analysis|result amount|unit|reference sequence.
How could i get it?

Comment: -1 I did mention about the [documentation of HL7](http://www.mexi.be/documents/hl7/httoc.htm) in your last post.

Comment: Better you point him to HL7.org  http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=185

Comment: haha we both can give enough pieces of documentation (-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the ORU^R01-Messages, especially at the OBX segments

```
OBX/14 Datetime
OBX/3  Observation Identifer
OBX/5  Observation Value
OBX/6  Units
OBX/7  Reference Range
```

and do not neglect the other fields

Comment: thanx sqlab, it's very helpful.